# Stimulsoft reports dataset sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

:-)
   We’ve been doing some further research on the Stimulsoft mobile designer with ASP.NET MVC using Razor view engine, consuming business objects or custom DataSets.

The issue is: we cannot find any reference (documentation or samples) on how the designer fetches the data neither how we can have some control on that mechanism in order to get the right data in the right amount.

Is there any way we can obtain more details over this?
Anyone with extensive experience using these tools in a Web App?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At this time if you use Data Source then the whole data from each Data Source are fetched into one DataSet.

If you use Business Objects, then before rendering report you register business object in a report and at render time only the necessary data are fetched.

Unfortunately, at this moment there is no way to control amount of data transferred to report engine as Data Source.
But using business Objects you could implement mechanism of transferring data to report engine.